# NextJS with ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net-core, iis, next.js, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a NextJS app with a backend written in ASP.NET Core. I need to host both of them on the same website in IIS.

I have managed to host the NextJS app, and I created an application and a virtual directory under my website and added the rewrite rule as in the following `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
            <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <!-- Redirect /api requests to the Web API application -->

            <!-- Handle Next.js routing -->
            <rule name="Next.js" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
            </rule>
            <rules>
                <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                    </rule>

                    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                    <rule name="StaticContent">
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
                    </rule>

                    <!-- Handle requests to the Web API -->
                    <rule name="API Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^api/(.*)" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3005/{R:1}" />
                    </rule>

                    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </rewrite>

            <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <hiddenSegments>
                        <add segment="node_modules" />
                    </hiddenSegments>
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>

            <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
            <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
            <iisnode node_env="production" />

            <!-- You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
                 * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
                 * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
                 * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled
                 See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
            -->
            <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However whenever I access http://localhost:3005/api, it show page not found in NextJS (so the NextJS is handling the route).

How to solve this?

Comment: When you access `http://localhost:3005/api`, it cannot be forwarded to the Web API application, because the first rule is not executed. Please try using FRT to trace rewrite rules, you can see how the rules are used internally. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

As Nextjs (v13.4.x) has the built in backend `/api` route mapped to `pages/api` folder, you need to add rewrite config in next.js for server side rendering function: `getServerSideProps` if you use SSR. Only frontend React side can hit API proxy of web.config but not server side which Nextjs handles.

You need to add rewrites in next.config.js file similar to this:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination: '<ASP.NET Core API URL>/:path*',
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: Can we have both in the same site (same port) on IIS?

Comment: Nextjs and asp.net api applications need to be deployed on different ports. The reverse proxy still needs to hit a different port (at least based on 12-factor app approach)